# Enlarge or save Github's branching / network graph

Tags: google-chrome, github, google-chrome-devtools

In a presentation, I want to show a repo's network graph generated by GitHub, (example: https://github.com/electron/electronjs.org/network), but the display area is so tiny, I have to drag and drag and drag.

How can I make it larger? I don't care if it's a screenshot or live, as long as it's larger.

I'm aware that many GUIs can show such a graph, but I want to use Github's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome with `--headless` and `--screenshot` flags to take a screenshot of the rendered document

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot --window-size=2400,2000 https://github.com/electron/electronjs.org/network
```

See

- [Getting Started with Headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)
- [Using headless Chrome as an automated screenshot tool](https://medium.com/@dschnr/using-headless-chrome-as-an-automated-screenshot-tool-4b07dffba79a)

Comment: Did it work for you? The graph size doesn't respond to the windows size, it's always very small no matter how big your screen is, so I doubt it'd work.

Comment: Yes, the dimensions passed were maintained. Tried 2400,2000 as well, which are probably closer to the dimensions that make the increased scale apparent.

Comment: I'm not a command line expert, so I didn't really know what to do. I tried pasting it into cmd, powershell, and gitbash, at my chrome install path, but non produced any screenshot.png

Comment: What is the path to the Chrome executable at your OS?

Comment: Hi, I tried to run cmd in administrator mode, and it worked! However, the screenshot turns out exactly the same as what I see in the browser, which has a very tiny window for the graph.Open the link and drag the graph and you'll know what I mean.